# Navigation menu in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm looking at implementing a menu (something like [this](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html)). What is the right way to do it? I didn't find any examples in Yesod itself, nor other libraries that do it.

Comment: Well you obviously *did* find a way to implement it, as you linked to one. All you have to do now is convert that into some template/widget code, which should be almost one-to-one and which is well documented in the book. So... what is missing? Is there a specific point where you are struggling?

Comment: I'm looking for the _logic_ that's missing, like giving an `active` class for the active menu item, or different items per user. I was expecting something like `YesodBreadcrumbs` but for menus

Answer (score 1):

The problem description sounds like something I would mostly handle on the client-side with js and possibly ajax or even with form elements + clever css.

I assume most sites that are built with Yesod these days don't have more than maybe a half dozen navigation entries so a separate subsystem just for menues wasn't something many people needed. But maybe I overlooked something, so [take](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-cookbook/tree/master/cookbook) a [look](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Yesod) yourself.

That being said, it should be relatively simple to develop your own subsystem if you really need it. After all, all you need is for some little piece of hamlet to change based on an enum or something.

Comment: thanks, I've indeed gone over the cookbook, didn't find anything there. I'm also writing a lot of decoupled sites, but I'm looking at the "base" functionality of yesod, to see what we have out of the box.

So regarding my task, do you know what would be the right way to get the current handler/ route?

Comment: @amitaibu Simple: if your handler is running, then it's the current one. But please ask new questions as separate questions so they are easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example of what I've ended up with:

```
-- Foundation.hs

data MenuItem = MenuItem
  { _menuItemLabel :: Text
  , _menuItemRoute :: Route App
  , _menuItemAccessCallback :: Bool
  } deriving (Show)

instance Yesod App where
  -- ...

  defaultLayout widget = do
      -- ...
      muser <- maybeAuthPair
      mcurr <- getCurrentRoute

      -- All the menu items.
     let menuItems =
          [ MenuItem
            { _menuItemLabel = "Home"
            , _menuItemRoute = HomeR
            -- Always show menu item.
            , _menuItemAccessCallback = True
            }
          , MenuItem
            { _menuItemLabel = "People"
            , _menuItemRoute = PeopleR
            -- Example for item that shows only if user is authenticated.
            , _menuItemAccessCallback = isJust muser
            }
          ]

      -- Filter items to show only accessible items
      let filteredMenuItems = [x | x <- menuItems, _menuItemAccessCallback x == True]
```

And inside the default template file:

```
-- default-layout.hamlet
<nav>
  $forall MenuItem label route _ <- filteredMenuItems
    <a class="item" :Just route == mcurr:.active href="@{route}">#{label}
```